# Binding a ListView and formatting data based on value

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a `ListView` with an `ItemTemplate` item as below:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChangeOrders"><%#Eval("sum")%></asp:Label>
```

What I need is if the sum is negative I need to set font color as `RED` and remove the minus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `DataBinding` method on the contorl itself.

Example:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChangeOrders"
    OnDataBinding="lbChangeOrder_DataBinding"></asp:Label>

protected void lbChangeOrder_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);    
    double sum = (double)(Eval("Sum"));
    if (sum < 0)
    {
        sum *= -1;
        lbl.ForeColor = "Red";
    }
    lbl.Text = sum.ToString();     
}
```

I prefer to do all these type of tweeks at the control level so you can swap out the control and you know everything that is tied to it.  If you do it at the `ItemDataBound` level, it is not as localized to the control itself.  Very rarely do I ever use the `ItemDataBound` event.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to use the [ItemDataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) and do a check of sum.  If it is negative then assign a CSS Class that will color that element red.